# Unable to run tests in parallel using TestNG

Tags: java, testng

I am unable to get my tests to run in parallel, despite using a parallel data provider.

I don't write my own XML files.  To run tests, I simply use the auto-generated XML file when I right click in Eclipse and say Run as -> TestNG Test.

Here's my data provider:

```
@DataProvider(parallel = true)
protected final Object[][] dataProvider() {
    ...code
}
```

Here is my factory:

```
@Factory(dataProvider = "dataProvider")
public TesterClass(String s) {
...code instantiation...
}
```

Shouldn't TestNG instantiate the two classes in parallel and run their test methods in parallel (so `test1()` of the first instantiation runs at the same time as `test1()` of the second instantiation)?

Comment: Why not just use a .xml file? makes life so much easier and it works. The .xml file should start similar to this:  <suite name="Suite" parallel="classes" verbose="2" thread-count="2">   Let me know if you want me to post my full xml file as an answer

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.  Thanks!